# selenium + java - how to download a pdf and save with a different name?

Tags: java, selenium, download, google-chrome-headless

As part of a work on an existing selenium test pack, I was asked to remove the instantiation of Firefox to download server-generated PDF documents - an authentication issue led to an agent config session error that prevented the documents from being downloaded.

When the document is generated in the server, it can be accessed via a URL that contains a UUID. This URL was passed to a fresh instance of Firefox and the document could be downloaded.

This selenium pack was thrown together **NOT** following the best practices of software development some 10 years ago. Though it worked, for the most part, its performance is quite poor.

I can access the generated document on the server with the service URL plus the UUID as part of the path, as this is part of the document generation process. In the current workflow, there is a 'generate document' button that is clicked by the running pack.

Once this document is generated, I need to download it to a specific folder and rename it to serve as proof the process has been completed to satisfaction.

I searched a lot and found a few articles that gave me insights into parts of the issue, but could not put together a working solution.

I can start chrome driver in headless mode but haven't figured out how to download the document. Since the browser window displays the document itself, there is no clickable download button on the page.

Can anyone point me to a solution here?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I worked on similar kind of thing if possible can you provide more details. To reproduce this can I do anything similar in my local? Like, there is a PDF in my machine and I opened with help of chrome then I can see download button

Comment: @NandanA, thanks for your comment. Indeed I can see the download button when I open a PDF on my web browser. I meant there is no download button or link for the document on the application. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I will post an answer.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the pdf document by some implementation of wget?

Comment: Posted an answer please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently while opening `pdf` in chrome we can see the download option but through `selenium` we cannot perform any actions on that download button. Here our goal is to download the pdf into desired location so we need to `disable` the `pdf` plugins before launching the driver. Please see the below code,

**Required ChromOptions:**

```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       chromeOptionsMap.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer" });
       chromeOptionsMap.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
       chromeOptionsMap.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\test\\");
       options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromeOptionsMap);
       options.addArguments("--headless");
```

**Accessing PDF:**

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Bill.pdf");
```

## Explanation:

***plugins.plugins_disabled*** --> *Disables viewing `pdf` in chrome.*

***plugins.always_open_pdf_externally*** --> *Downloads the `pdf` on launching the respective link or `URI`.*

***download.default_directory*** --> *Default download location can be changed.*

Comment: This looks nice! I'll try it out now! The downloaded file has the same name as the source file, correct?

Comment: Yes. If you want you can modify but that needs little more code. Please make sure to change the path here `chromeOptionsMap.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\test\\");`

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to remove `options.addArguments("--headless");` because otherwise the driver stop loading pages

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it using plain Selenium, but try to use AutoIT for it:

https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-download-upload-files-using-selenium-with-java/